# none of the functions that has a for loop in are working

Tags: python-3.x

```
from Assign4.country import Country
class CountryCatalogue:



    def __init__(self, countryFile):
        lineCount = 0
        self.countryCat = []
        database = open(countryFile, "r", encoding="utf-8")
        for line in database:
            fields = line.rstrip("\n").split("|")
            #if lineCount != 0:
            self.countryCat.append(Country(fields[0],fields[2],fields[3],fields[1]))
            lineCount += 1




    def setPopulationOfCountry(self,nameOfCountry,population):
        for x in range(len(self.countryCat)):
            if self.countryCat[x].name == nameOfCountry:
                self.countryCat[x].population = population


    def setAreaOfCountry(self,nameOfCountry,area):
        for x in range(len(self.countryCat)):
            if self.countryCat[x].name == nameOfCountry:
                self.countryCat[x].area = area


    def setContinentOfCountry(self,nameOfCountry,continent):
        for x in range(len(self.countryCat)):
            if self.countryCat[x].name == nameOfCountry:
                self.countryCat[x].continent = continent


    def findCountry(self,country):
        for x in range(len(self.countryCat)):
            i = None
            if self.countryCat[x].name == country:
                i = x
        if i != None:
            return self.countryCat[i]
        return None




    def addCountry(self,countryName,pop,area,cont):
        presence = False
        for x in range(len(self.countryCat)):
            if self.countryCat[x].name == countryName:
                presence = True
        if presence == False:
            self.countryCat.append(Country(countryName,pop,area,cont))
            return True
        return False


    def printCountryCatalogue(self):
        i = 0



lst = CountryCatalogue("data.txt")
print(lst.findCountry("Canada"))
```

Why aren't the functions working at all? When I try to use them, they just return `None` no matter what I input.

Comment: When you say they aren't working, what do you mean? what errors do you get? How are you calling them?

Answer (score 1):

You need to break out of your loops when you've found a match.

```
from io import StringIO    

class Country:
    def __init__(self, name, continent):
        self.name, self.continent = name, continent    

class CountryCatalogue:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.countryCat = []
        for line in db:
            fields = line.rstrip("\n").split("|")
            self.countryCat.append(Country(fields[0], fields[1]))

    def findCountry(self, country):
        for item in self.countryCat:
            if item.name == country:
                return item

data = '''\
Brazil|South America
Canada|North America
China|Asia
India|Asia
'''

catalog = CountryCatalogue(StringIO(data))

print(catalog.findCountry('Canada'))
print(catalog.findCountry('asdfasdf asdfas'))
```